# How to rename the columns names using loops in R

Tags: r

I have a data table with 50 columns. Is it possible to use loops in R to rename the columns names as Col_1, ..., Col_50?
I know I can rename the columns with "setNames" function, but then I have to define the names for each columns. Since, the first part of the column names does not change, i.e "Col", I was thinking to use the loop for the numbers. But I am not sure if I can do it. Does it make sense to use loops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `paste` which is vectorized.

```
names(df1) <- paste0("Col_", seq_along(df1))
```